# Deciphering a Confusing Function Prototype

Tags: c

I have the following function prototype:

```
char *(*scan)(char *, char *, char *, char *, int , int);
```

scanleft() is a function and has the type of static char *.

When I try to compile, I found that there is a pointer type mismatch between scan and scanleft.

```
if ((subtype & 1) ^ zero) scan = scanleft; else scan = scanright;
```

What does the prototype of scan() mean?

Comment: that "function prototype" looks like a function pointer.

Comment: What do you mean by “scanleft() is a fuction and has the type of static char *.”? The keyword `static` is not part of a type, and `char *` is not a function type. Unrelated, what is `zero`? If it’s a numeric constant with value `0`, why not just use that? If it’s something else, why call it `zero`?

Comment: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*%28*scan%29%28char+*%2C+char+*%2C+char+*%2C+char+*%2C+int+%2C+int%29%3B)

Comment: To flesh out the above comment a little: the cdecl program (or the website http://cdecl.org) is your friend--it converts C declarations to English and vice versa.  In the case of the above scan declaration, it yields: "declare scan as pointer to function (pointer to char, pointer to char, pointer to char, pointer to char, int, int) returning pointer to char"

Comment: How is `scanleft` declared? We are not interested in vague verbal description. Post the exact full declaration of `scanleft`.

Answer (score 2):

`scan` is not a function; it has no prototype.

`scan` is a pointer to a function (taking a pointer to `char`, pointer to `char`, pointer to `char`, pointer to `char`, `int`, and `int`) and returning a pointer to `char`.

According to your description, `scanleft` isn't a function either; it's a pointer to `char`.

---

The only prototype in your question is this:

```
char *, char *, char *, char *, int , int
```

... which doesn't look particularly confusing to me. It's 6 straightforward parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *(*scan)(char *, char *, char *, char *, int , int);
```

This defines a function pointer `scan`, which points to a function that accepts four `char *` and two `int` parameters, and returns a `char *`.

That means you can do things like:

```
char *scanLeft(char *p1, char *p2, char *p3, char *p4, int p5, int p6) {
    // do something
}
char *scanRight(char *p1, char *p2, char *p3, char *p4, int p5, int p6) {
    // do something else
}
:
scan = scanLeft;  char *xyzzy = scan("a", "b", "c", "d", 271828, 314159);
scan = scanRight; char *plugh = scan("a", "b", "c", "d", 271828, 314159);
```

and the two calls via the `scan` function pointer will go to *different* functions.